# How to clean up substreams in continuous Akka streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Given I have a very long running stream of events flowing through something as show below. When a long time has passed there will be lots of sub streams created that is no longer needed.

> Is there a way to clean up a specific substream at a given time, for
>   example the substream created by id 3 should be cleaned and the state
>   in the scan method lost at 13Pm (expires property of Wid)?

```
case class Wid(id: Int, v: String, expires: LocalDateTime)
test("Substream with scan") {
  val (pub, sub) = TestSource.probe[Wid]
    .groupBy(Int.MaxValue, _.id)
    .scan("")((a: String, b: Wid) => a + b.v)
    .mergeSubstreams
    .toMat(TestSink.probe[String])(Keep.both)
    .run()
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR** You can close a substream after some time. However, using input to dynamically set the time with built-in stages is another matter.

**Closing a substream**

To close a flow, you usually complete it (from upstream), but you can also cancel it (from downstream). For instance, the `take(n: Int)` flow will cancel once `n` elements have gone through.

Now, in the `groupBy` case, you cannot complete a substream, since upstream is shared by all substreams, but you can cancel it. How depends on what condition you want to put on its end.

However, be aware that `groupBy` removes inputs for subflows that have already been closed: If a new element with id `3` comes from upstream to the `groupBy` after the `3`-substream has been closed, it will simply be ignored and the next element will be pulled in. The reason for this is probably that some elements might be lost in the process between closing and re-opening of the substream. Also, if your stream is supposed to run for a very long time, this will affect performances because each element will be checked against the list of closed substreams before being forwarded to the relevant (live) substream. You might want to implement your own stateful filter (say, with a bloom filter) if you're not satisfied with the performances of this.

To close a substream, I usually use either `take` (if you want only a given number of elements, but that's probably not the case on an infinite stream), or some kind of timeout: either `completionTimeout` if you want a fixed time from materialization to closure or `idleTimeout` if you want to close when no element have been coming through for some time. Note that these flows do not cancel the stream but fail it, so you have to catch the exception with a `recover` or `recoverWith` stage to change the failure into a cancel (`recoverWith` allows you to cancel without sending any last element, by recovering with `Source.empty`).

**Dynamically set the timeout**

Now what you want is to set dynamically the closing time according to the first passing element. This is more complicated because materialization of streams is independant of the elements that pass through them. Indeed, in the usual (without `groupBy`) case, streams are materialized before any element go through them, so it makes no sense to use elements to materialize them.

I had similar issues in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862590/can-the-subflows-of-groupby-depend-on-the-keys-they-were-generated-from), and ended up using a modified version of `groupBy` with signature

```
paramGroupBy[K, OO, MM](maxSubstreams: Int, f: Out => K, paramSubflow: K => Flow[Out, OO, MM])
```

that allows to define every substream using the key that defined it. This can be modified to have the first element (instead of the key), as parameter.

Another (probably simpler, in your case) way would be to write your own stage that does exactly what you want: get end-time from first element and cancel the stream at that time. Here is an example implementation for this (I used a scheduler instead of setting a state):

```
object CancelAfterTimer

class CancelAfter[T](getTimeout: T => FiniteDuration) extends GraphStage[FlowShape[T, T]] {
  val in = Inlet[T]("CancelAfter.in")
  val out = Outlet[T]("CancelAfter.in")
  override val shape: FlowShape[T, T] = FlowShape(in, out)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = new TimerGraphStageLogic(shape) with InHandler with OutHandler  {
    override def onPush(): Unit = {
      val elem = grab(in)
      if (!isTimerActive(CancelAfterTimer))
        scheduleOnce(CancelAfterTimer, getTimeout(elem))
      push(out, elem)
    }

    override def onTimer(timerKey: Any): Unit = 
      completeStage() //this will cancel the upstream and close the downstrean

    override def onPull(): Unit = pull(in)

    setHandlers(in, out, this)
  }
}
```