# How to pool Akka substreams

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to maintain a long running Akka stream, that fans into substreams (lets say to conflate/throttle/writeToDB records with a particular ID).
Because the stream should be kept alive for a long time, at one point the stream will be out of available substreams (And I'd like to clear unused memory anyway).

1. How can I cleanup the 'idle' substreams? (The doc points to `idleTimeout` and `recoverWithRetries`, but to me it does not seem to actually liberate a substream. Am I not using it properly? I can see that `recoverWithRetries` is called at the right time, but the next `MAX_SUBSTREAMS + 1`th key that arrives later still fails (`Cannot open a new substream as there are too many substreams open`))
2. How to handle the case that maybe, there is no substream to clean? (can I / how do I  slow down the upstream?)
3. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016410/how-to-clean-up-substreams-in-continuous-akka-streams) says that

   > groupBy removes inputs for subflows that have already been closed

This is not what I want, I need the substream to just be re-created in that case. Also I cannot find any mention of this behaviour in the doc.

In the end, what I need is to fan out a stream into a pool of substreams. If all substreams are used, slow down upstream. If a substream does not receive any new record for x seconds, emit, clear it and move it back to the pool.

```
Flow.of(Record.class)
    .groupBy(MAX_SUBSTREAMS, Record::getKey)
    .via(conflateThenThrottleThenCommitRecord)
    .idleTimeout(Duration.of(2, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
    .recoverWithRetries(1, new PFBuilder()
        .matchAny(ex -> Source.empty())
        .build())
    .mergeSubstreams();
```